# libgdx texture rendering on mesh and Affine Transformation

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, mesh, affinetransform

I am using libgdx to create a virtual trial room app. I am new to both Java and libgdx, so I might be wrong somewhere.

I plan to create a shader and a Mesh, and a texture is rendered on the Mesh(texture is a fabric of purple color with stripes). Then I plan to do affine transformation of very small triangles(shear, rotate, transform or translate) in the mesh to form a shirt(2D image) like below.

My idea is when the triangles transform, they take with them the part of texture with them, and the texture is modified.

[image: Fabric]
[image: Shirt]

Initially when I try to render the texture on the mesh, it shows a black screen instead of the purple fabric. My code:

```
public class MyAffineTransformation implements ApplicationListener {

Texture img;
String vertexShader;
String fragmentShader;
Mesh mesh;
ShaderProgram shader;

private float[] verts = new float[MAX_VERTS * NUM_COMPONENTS]; //Used to     make triangles
private int idx = 0; //The index position

@Override
public void create() {

    img = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("fabric.jpg"));
    img.setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.Repeat);
    img.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

    mesh = new Mesh(true, 3, 3, new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, POSITION_COMPONENTS, ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE),
            new VertexAttribute(Usage.TextureCoordinates, 2, ShaderProgram.TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE));

    mesh.setVertices(new float[] { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0.5f });
    mesh.setIndices(new short[] { 0, 1, 2 });

    //Shader - vertex and fragment shader are posted below
    vertexShader = Gdx.files.internal("affine.vert").readString();
    fragmentShader = Gdx.files.internal("affine.frag").readString();
    shader = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glEnable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    img.bind();
    mesh.render(shader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
```

My Vertex Shader:

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
void main() {
 v_texCoords = a_texCoord; 
 gl_Position =  u_projTrans * a_position; 
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
#define LOWP lowp
precision mediump float;
#else
#define LOWP
#endif
varying LOWP vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main()
{ 
 gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
}
```

It shows a black screen as of now. Please help me render texture on Mesh.
Also, when that happens, is it possible to do Affine transfotmation(rotation, translation, scaling, shearing etc) of small triangles in the mesh to form a 2D shirt. Please let me know if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: Why not model it in 3D modeling software and UV wrap it there? Sounds like you are trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I was thinking to keep it simple. And i plan to record the movement of triangles from plain fabric to shirt(Affine transformation) and use that to derive similar cut shirts of other colors. So it is kind of a virtual trial room. So can I use some 3D modelling software to achieve the same? As in enable that click on fabric to get the shirt feature within the app?

Comment: To do affine transformations to achieve what you're talking about, you would have to make your mesh of many triangles. Then you could calculate the UV coordinates for each triangle in such a way as to stretch the texture to the shape you want. 3D modeling software already serves this purpose. You can model something in 3D software and load it using the 3D API of Libgdx.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you please suggest some tutorials for the same. It will really help me as I am new to both libgdx and Java.

Comment: All I know about is the official documentation and Xoppa's tutorials that are linked from the documentation.